# Does Django's EmailMessage object support the CC field?

Tags: django

I'm reading the [Django EmailMessage doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) and it doesn't mention the CC field.  What changes should I make so that I can put recipients in the CC field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Django doesn't support the CC field:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/mail.py#L193

However, here's a subclass that does:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/630/

Also, here's the ticket that explains the lack of a CC field:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5790